# Delete cookie values

Tags: session, cookie

In my controller function I'm setting cookie like

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
$cookie->set('frontAttributeLabel',$frontAttributeLabel ,time()+86400,'/');
```

In observer I'm retriving it's value and using it

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie'); 
$frontAttributeLabel = $cookie->get('frontAttributeLabel');
```

In the observer function it's working fine. After it's usage I'm deleting it using

```
$cookie->delete('frontAttributeLabel');
```

Once I'm done with the use of this observer (`catalog_product_load_after`) function, next time I'm visiting the page again I see it's previous value is set.
I'm using wrong function to delete cookie? or I need to pass more parameters in delete function?

Comment: try passing the path (`/`) as second argument in delete. And try using a `set` with a time in the past to delete if that doesn't work. If both don't work it's not a deleting issue but something else

Comment: @SanderMangel: Thanks. it worked :).  Please put it in answer section and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added it as answer. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing the path (`/`) as second argument in delete. And try using a `set` with a time in the past to delete if that doesn't work.

```
$cookie->set('frontAttributeLabel',$frontAttributeLabel ,time()-100,'/');
```

If both don't work it's not a deleting issue but something else